# Silverlight 4 Datagrid ColumnHeader Drag

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to allow a datagrid column to be dragged vertically and dropped into an area above the datagrid in Silverlight 4? Just like telerik. Thank you

Comment: What happens in the telerik control when you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AnthonyWJones Telerik's control groups the column dragged to the header. My guess is that it adds a PropertyGroupDescription with the name of the Column to a PagedCollection view which is the data context of the DataGrid:

(from the SilverlightToolkit online demos):

```
PagedCollectionView pcv = new PagedCollectionView(Contact.People);
pcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("State"));
pcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("City"));
myDataGrid.DataContext = pcv;
```

You can check the control user273340 is talking about here: http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/FirstLook

What I'm  not sure off is how they implement the draggin to the header stuff.